# How to connect a mobile application from your android mobile device to your laptop server using sockets?

Tags: java, android, client, wireless

I have a very simple Java server that runs on my laptop. On the other side i have my Tablet with also a very simple client to conect to my server but it is not working.
Both are running on the same wireless network.

Sample of the Server
        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        Socket socket = null;
        DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;
        DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;

```
    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8888);
        System.out.println("Listening :8888");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    while(true){
        try {
            socket = serverSocket.accept();
            dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            System.out.println("ip: " + socket.getInetAddress());
            System.out.println("message: " + dataInputStream.readUTF());
            dataOutputStream.writeUTF("Hello!");
```

Simple client code:

```
mysock = new Socket(server_adress, port_number);
```

Ive tried setting the manifest WIFI permissions. Tried shutting down the computer firewalls.
Is there something  i should know regarding how the wireless conection works that might be blocking the conection?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the value of `server_adress` in your client?

Comment: my current ip taken from the cmd line. 10.101.224.119

Comment: I would try to connect with some confirmed server (google?) then I'd try to connect with my own laptop using external and proven good software (i.e. Apache, XAMPP) to make sure everything is ok with the connection, addressing, firewall etc. If that would work, i'd try to connect with my own server. Did you try this kind of primitive debugging method?

Comment: The wireless routers I know have an option for disabling communication between different wireless devices. May be this is also true fro your router an it is activated. Can you ping the PC's IP from your Smartphone?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set permission for INTERNET.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Client side:

```
String adresaServer = "192.168.4.120";

        int PORT = 8095;
        Socket socket = null;

        DataInputStream in = null;

        try {
            socket = new Socket();
            SocketAddress adr = new InetSocketAddress(adresaServer, PORT);
            socket.connect(adr, 1500);

            out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            out.flush();
        } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
            System.err.println(" Error at CONNECTINGG: \n" + e);

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.err.println(" Serverul nu poate fi gasit \n" + e);
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        out.writeFloat(sensors.getValueGyroZ());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e) {

                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Server Side:

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = null;

        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
            serverSocket.setSoTimeout(1600000);

            System.out.println(" Waiting a client ... ");
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
            int i = 0;
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(
                    socket.getOutputStream());



            while (true) {


                DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(
                        socket.getInputStream());



            System.out.println(String.valueOf(in.readFloat()));

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(" Eroare IO \n" + e);


        } finally {
            try {
                serverSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> is there already is that it? Yep thats already in the manifest and still doesnt work :(

Comment: tell me if this works...if not i can post one of my server and client, because i just made an app like this

Comment: it didnt mate :( where you connecting yours like i want mine to? Your server running on your desktop/laptop and then connecting to it thru your client on the mobile device?

Comment: yes...i have a server made as a java desktop app, and client on the android device

Comment: This is my code that works, please try to adapt it in your situation and take it like example of structring, but not take it for granted(as you just need to play the code and will work)

Comment: Thanks mate its pretty much similar to what i have already. But its not connecting. I think its my wireless network. Nothing is reaching the server.

Comment: try to ping your server from cmd and see if packets arrive

Comment: well from my own computer it does, problem is from other computerse on the network. Ill have to try on a different network i think thats the problem. :(

Comment: are you sure on the client side you have setted the ip server as the ip of your computer?

Comment: Also there is an app on the android market called Ping & DNS. You can install it on your device and ping to your computer. This way you can see if the packets are sent to computer.

Comment: Thanks everyone it really was the network i was in. I switched networks and now it works fine.